# How to calculate objects' size in Cassandra programatically

Tags: cassandra, hector

I am new to Cassandra and was wondering how to calculate Cassandra cache size programmatically.

For example, after inserting several objects into Cassandra, I want to know what volume has been taken by those objects in Cassandra's memory table, via code.

The Cfstats are command-line tools, which does not meet my requirement.

Is there anything in the Hector API that can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The CLI tools actually use JMX to interrogate the Cassandra instance(s). You could use this approach programatically, but it would be cumbersome. This page has some details on the monitoring interface:

http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/operations/monitoring

There is no other API support for retrieval of cache statistics information.